# Creating Plots in Excel from a Python script

Tags: python, excel, charts

Is it possible to write a Python script that will create and save a chart in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I read here

http://python-excel.googlegroups.com/web/python-excel.pdf?gda=xZW5Y0IAAAAK26IHZlH6sZ8eLgsep540qvBo1o93MWeCIftQ3v-jMNXEtWX7y7b6ByPnawQ3OxpV4u3aa4iAIyYQIqbG9naPgh6o8ccLBvP6Chud5KMzIQ

There are still reasons why automating an Excel instance via COM is necessary:
**• manipulation of graphs** 
• rich text cells
• reading formulae in cells
• working with macros and names
• the more esoteric things found in .xls files

So you probably will need C# or something like that and the client machine will need to have excel installed..

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer? I am new to stack overflow..dunno if asking to mark as answer is something valid..

Comment: You don't need C# or something like that. You can use Python and the pywin32 package to manipulate Excel files. It is well supported, has been around since Python 1.x, and lots of people use it. I use it for testing xlrd (dump file using xlrd, dump file using win32com, compare results).

Comment: As far as I know, yes, there's an API for just about anything that a user can do with Excel, a mouse, and a keyboard.